# ngResource with async response interceptor

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, interceptor, ngresource

I'm writing a response intercepter for an API call with ngResource like this:

```
var Thing = $resource('/api/things/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
  queryAll: {
    method: 'GET',
    interceptor: {
      response: function(response) {
        var instance = response.resource;

        doAsyncStuffHere(instance.data);

        return instance;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The interceptor function should enrich the data from the response but returns the unmodified instance before the async stuff is done (as expected, since it's async...).

Is there a good way, to enrich the data asynchronously and make the return statement "wait" until it's done? Callback? Promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the right question, i've found an article who solved my issue:

> Sometimes there is a need to make some asynchronous operations inside the interceptor. Luckily AngularJS allows us to return a promise that will be resolved later. This will defer the request sending in case of request interceptor and will defer the response resolving in case of response interceptor.

From: http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/

And here is what my code now looks like and working like a charm.

```
var Thing = $resource('/api/things/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
  queryAll: {
    method: 'GET',
    interceptor: {
      response: function(response) {
        var instance  = response.resource,
            _deferred = $q.defer();

        doAsyncStuffHere(instance.data).then(function() {
            _deferred.resolve(instance);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Use o exemplo:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/http#$http-arguments;

A propriedade "transformRequest" é uma melhor opção;

Comment: I'm afraid the formatting is broken, the language different from the one in the question, and the answer lacks explanation.